# Export Word to XPS c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, xps

As part of an application i need a window  where the users can get a preview of office documents in a way that is clear to them that it is read-only. Also, the window is is only part of the screen so opening a full version of an Office app with ribbon an all takes a little to much space. The users will be browsing through a lot of documents so it has to be fast, speed is the key.

I found out this, with a lot of help from google and this site and others:
it shows the document in read only; check.
It send the xpsfil back to a windows form to be viewed without taking up space on the screen than it has to; check.
Speed; ohh no. It is so slow.
Does anybod know of a better way of viewing office documents fast and in a way that is clearly read-only to the users?
Help much appriciated

```
    private readonly string TEMP = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%tmp%");
    private  object nullObject = Type.Missing;


    private string ConvertWordtoXps(string wordDocName)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        wordApp.Documents.Open(wordDocName, ConfirmConversions: false, ReadOnly: true);
        string xpsFileName = String.Concat(TEMP, "\\", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(wordDocName), ".xps");

        try
        {
            //wordApp.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(xpsFileName, WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatXPS, false, WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForOnScreen, WdExportRange.wdExportAllDocument, 1, 1, WdExportItem.wdExportDocumentContent, false, true, WdExportCreateBookmarks.wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, false, true, false, nullObject);
            wordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2(xpsFileName, FileFormat: WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXPS);
            return xpsFileName;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application)wordApp).Quit(SaveChanges: false, OriginalFormat: nullObject, RouteDocument: nullObject);
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Comment: I guess you could always set the word file to read only mode with a password.